# Finding all documents within date range and within distance of point

Tags: mongodb

I'm working on a system that allows users to signup to receive alerts about new events posted within a certain distance of a location during a particular date range.

When a user signs up for an alert, I create a document that looks like this:

```
{
    "_id":"5b43ab8eb0a638000e188615",
    "confirmed":true,
    "confirmed_at":"2018-07-10T14:20:51.078Z",
    "created_at":"2018-07-09T18:38:06.874Z",
    "date_start":"2018-07-30T00:00:00.000Z",
    "date_end":"2018-08-31T00:00:00.000Z",
    "email":"me@example.com",
    "location":{
        "type":"Point",
        "coordinates": [-90.44065060000003,31.5790588]
    },
    "location_name":"Brookhaven, MS 39601, USA",
    "distance":150,
    "unsubscribed":false,
    "unsubscribed_at":null
}
```

There is also a `2dspehere` index on the location field.

When a new event is created, I need to be able to query the collection for all documents that have a `date_start` and `date_end` range that contains the date of the event and that has a sphere that contains the location of the event.

Given an event that looks like this:

```
{
    start_date: "2018-08-01",
    latitude: 30.6954595,
    longitude: -88.174414
}
```

I would expect that the document above would be returned because the event's start date falls within the given range, and the event is within 150 miles (147 to be exact) of the desired location.

Also something to note is that events themselves do not exist in MongoDB. They are created and managed in a separate system, and we will be querying that system's API periodically get the newly created events.

This is my first foray into the Geo-Spatial aspects of mongodb, so I'm unsure of how to approach this. I've been playing around with using the `$geoWithin` and `$centerSphere` operators, but can't seem to get them to work.

Is what I'm attempting possible a single query from within MongoDB, or will I need to, for example, pull out all the documents that meet the data range criteria and in the application iterate through the documents to see if their sphere contains the event's location?

I think I've included all the pertinent information, but if more info is needed, just ask and I'll update the question.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

After much googling and reading the documentation for MongoDB, I think I have come to what is the proper answer for this question, and thought I would share it for anyone that may stumble upon this question in the future.

So, the best way to solve this problem seems to be to make use of MongoDB's aggregation framework.

To arrive at the answer I needed, I had to setup a 3 stage aggregation pipeline.

The first step is to the use the `$geoNear` stage ([documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/geoNear/#pipe._S_geoNear)). This allows me to pass in the coordinates of the event in question from the external data source as well as the event's date. Using those values, I created a stage that looks like this:

```
{
    $geoNear: {
        near: { type: "Point", coordinates: [event-longitude-goes-here,event-latitude-goes-here]},
        distanceField: "calculated_distance" /** This field is appended to the returned documents */,
        distanceMultiplier: 0.000621371 /** This converts meters to miles */,
        maxDistance: 804672 /** this is 500 miles expressed in meters */,
        query: {
            /** This lets us do a preliminary filter of the documents so we don't do so many distance calculations */
            confirmed: true,
            unsubscribed: false,
            date_start: {$lte: Date('event-start-date-here')},
            date_end: {$gte: Date('event-start-date-here-again')}
        },
        spherical: true
    }
}
```

This gives me a set of documents whose `date_start` and `date_end` range contains the event start date, and whose distance is 500 miles or less from the event's coordinates. And just a note, the 500 mile max distance is used because that is the maximum distance that a user can request alerts for, so there is no reason to return documents further away than that.

Next, I need to add a `$project` stage ([documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/)) so that I can pull out only the fields that I want. This stage also allows me to do a comparison of two different fields in the document itself. As far as I'm away, comparing two document fields is not allowed in the upcoming `$match` stage.

```
{
    $project: {
        _id: 1,
        email: 1,
        location_name: 1,
        calculated_distance: 1,
        distance: 1,
        ofInterest: {$gte: ["$distance", "$calculated_distance"]}
    }
}
```

The `ofInterest` field in the projection adds a new field to the documents returned from the `$geoNear` stage. If `$distance` is greater than or equal to `$calculated_distance` this field will be `true` otherwise it will be `false`.

Finally, I create a `$match` stage ([documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/)) that pulls out all of the documents whose `$ofInterest` fields are `true`.

```
{
    $match: {
        ofInterest: true
    }
}
```

The resulting Document Collection will contain only those documents that meet the date criteria and that have a distance value that is greater than the distance of the user to the event.

The full `aggregate` call ends up looking like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{
    $geoNear: {
        near: { type: "Point", coordinates: [-88.174414,30.6954595]},
        distanceField: "calculated_distance",
        distanceMultiplier: 0.000621371,
        maxDistance: 804672,
        query: {
            confirmed: true,
            unsubscribed: false,
            date_start: {$lte: Date('2018-07-30')},
            date_end: {$gte: Date('2018-07-30')}
        },
        spherical: true
    }
},
{
    $project: {
        _id: 1,
        email: 1,
        location_name: 1,
        calculated_distance: 1,
        distance: 1,
        ofInterest: {$gte: ["$distance", "$calculated_distance"]}
    }
},
{
    $match: {
        ofInterest: true
    }
}]);
```

It was a bit more involved to arrive at this answer than I initially thought it would be, but I think it is pretty straightforward once you understand what's going on.